# Why can't I set custom pagination in AdminLTE / laravel 9 app?

Tags: laravel, adminlte

Working with AdminLTE(3.2.0) in laravel 9
I want to make custom pagination and I run command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

and in file  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I added line :

```
    public function boot()
    {
        JetstrapFacade::useAdminLte3();
//        \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::useBootstrap(); // If to uncomment this line it does not help
        Paginator::useBootstrapFour();

        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
           ...
```

I cleared cache and I expected that file resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-4.blade.php
must be used, but I do not see my changes in this file are applied.

I also tried to modify files
resources/views/vendor/pagination/bootstrap-5.blade.php and
resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php

What is wrong ?

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

I can set custom pagination in blade file, like :

```
 {{ $variables->links('vendor.pagination.simple-bootstrap-4') }}
```